# Part of the standalone tikzpicture gets scaled when pasting it in a document

Tags: tikz-pgf, scaling

I created this nice Polygon 
[image]
using the following code

```
\documentclass[margin=0pt]{standalone}
%---------------------------- Tikz Libraries ------------------------------%
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations, decorations.markings} 
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, arrows.meta}

%==========================  Middle & pointing arrows ==========================%
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------%
% usage: \draw[->-] or \draw[->-=6pt red 1]
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------%
\tikzset{ ->-/.style args={#1 #2 #3}{
         decoration={markings,mark= at position 0.5 with {\arrow{stealth}}, }, 
            postaction={decorate}, }, 
        ->-/.default= {0.5 6pt black }}


%==========================  Middle & pointing arrows ==========================%
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------%
% usage: \draw[-<-] path; or \draw[-<-=6pt red 1] path;
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------%
\tikzset{ -<-/.style args={#1 #2 #3}{
        decoration={markings,mark= at position 0.5 with {\arrow[>=stealth]{<}}, }, 
        postaction={decorate}, }, 
    -<-/.default= {0.5 6pt black }}


    \begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    %Polygon 12 Seiten
    \node[fill=gray!10] (pol) [ 
    %draw, 
    minimum size=0.9\textwidth, regular polygon, regular polygon sides=12, rotate=195 ]{};
    \foreach \x/\y/\i in {1/2/1,5/6/2,9/10/3} %\alpha's
    \draw[black!10!red,auto=right,->-]
    (pol.corner \x)--(pol.corner \y)
    node[black!10!red,midway]{$\alpha_{\i}$};
    \foreach \x/\y/\i in {3/4/1,7/8/2,11/12/3} %inverse \alpha's
    \draw[black!10!red,auto=right,-<-]
    (pol.corner \x)--(pol.corner \y)
    node[black!10!red,midway]{$\alpha_{\i}$};
    \foreach \x/\y/\i in {2/3/1,6/7/2,10/11/3} %\beta's
    \draw[black!10!blue,auto=right,->-]
    (pol.corner \x)--(pol.corner \y)
    node[black!10!blue,midway]{$\beta_ {\i}$};
    \foreach \x/\y/\i in {4/5/1,8/9/2,12/1/3} %inverse \beta's
    \draw[black!10!blue,auto=right,-<-]
    (pol.corner \x)--(pol.corner \y)
    node[black!10!blue,midway]{$\beta_{\i}$};

    %\xi's
    \draw[black!40!green,decoration={ markings, mark=at position 0.5 with {\arrow{stealth}}}, postaction={decorate}]  
    (0,-5.44) --(-2.21,-0.63) node[midway, left] {$\xi_1$} ;
    \draw[black!40!green,decoration={ markings, mark=at position 0.5 with {\arrow{stealth}}}, postaction={decorate}]  
    (0,-5.44) -- (0,-20pt) node[midway, left] {$\xi_2$};
    \draw[black!40!green,decoration={ markings, mark=at position 0.5 with {\arrow{stealth}}}, postaction={decorate}] 
    (0,-5.44) -- (2.21,-0.63) node[midway, left] {$\xi_3$};

    % 3 Kreise mit Beschriftung
    \draw[violet,decoration={markings, mark=at position 0.26 with {\arrow[>=stealth]{<}}},
    postaction={decorate},fill=white] (-2.5,0) circle (20pt)  ;
    \node[violet,above] at (-2.5,20pt) {$\rho_1$};
    \draw[violet,decoration={markings, mark=at position 0.26 with {\arrow[>=stealth]{<}}},
    postaction={decorate},fill=white] (0,0) circle (20pt);
    \node[violet,above] at (0,20pt) {$\rho_2$};
    \draw[violet,decoration={markings, mark=at position 0.26 with {\arrow[>=stealth]{<}}},
    postaction={decorate},fill=white] (2.5,0) circle (20pt);
    \node[violet,above] at (2.5,20pt) {$\rho_3$};

    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Now, I tried to copy and paste this code into my paper. Here is a minimal example

```
    \documentclass[oneside, a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations, decorations.markings} 
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix, arrows, decorations.pathmorphing}


%==========================  Middle & pointing arrows ==========================%
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------%
% usage: \draw[->-] or \draw[->-=6pt red 1]
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------%
\tikzset{ ->-/.style args={#1 #2 #3}{
        decoration={markings,mark= at position 0.5 with {\arrow{stealth}}, }, 
        postaction={decorate}, }, 
    ->-/.default= {0.5 6pt black }}


%==========================  Middle & pointing arrows ==========================%
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------%
% usage: \draw[-<-] path; or \draw[-<-=6pt red 1] path;
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------%
\tikzset{ -<-/.style args={#1 #2 #3}{
        decoration={markings,mark= at position 0.5 with {\arrow[>=stealth]{<}}, }, 
        postaction={decorate}, }, 
    -<-/.default= {0.5 6pt black }}


\begin{document}


    \begin{center}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        %Polygon 12 Seiten
        \node[fill=gray!10] (pol) [ 
        %draw, 
        minimum size=0.9\textwidth, regular polygon, regular polygon sides=12, rotate=195 ]{};
        \foreach \x/\y/\i in {1/2/1,5/6/2,9/10/3} %\alpha's
        \draw[black!10!red,auto=right,->-]
        (pol.corner \x)--(pol.corner \y)
        node[black!10!red,midway]{$\alpha_{\i}$};
        \foreach \x/\y/\i in {3/4/1,7/8/2,11/12/3} %inverse \alpha's
        \draw[black!10!red,auto=right,-<-]
        (pol.corner \x)--(pol.corner \y)
        node[black!10!red,midway]{$\alpha_{\i}$};
        \foreach \x/\y/\i in {2/3/1,6/7/2,10/11/3} %\beta's
        \draw[black!10!blue,auto=right,->-]
        (pol.corner \x)--(pol.corner \y)
        node[black!10!blue,midway]{$\beta_ {\i}$};
        \foreach \x/\y/\i in {4/5/1,8/9/2,12/1/3} %inverse \beta's
        \draw[black!10!blue,auto=right,-<-]
        (pol.corner \x)--(pol.corner \y)
        node[black!10!blue,midway]{$\beta_{\i}$};

        %\xi's
        \draw[black!40!green,decoration={ markings, mark=at position 0.5 with {\arrow{stealth}}}, postaction={decorate}]  
        (0,-5.44) --(-2.21,-0.63) node[midway, left] {$\xi_1$} ;
        \draw[black!40!green,decoration={ markings, mark=at position 0.5 with {\arrow{stealth}}}, postaction={decorate}]  
        (0,-5.44) -- (0,-20pt) node[midway, left] {$\xi_2$};
        \draw[black!40!green,decoration={ markings, mark=at position 0.5 with {\arrow{stealth}}}, postaction={decorate}] 
        (0,-5.44) -- (2.21,-0.63) node[midway, left] {$\xi_3$};

        % 3 Kreise mit Beschriftung
        \draw[violet,decoration={markings, mark=at position 0.26 with {\arrow[>=stealth]{<}}},
        postaction={decorate},fill=white] (-2.5,0) circle (20pt)  ;
        \node[violet,above] at (-2.5,20pt) {$\rho_1$};
        \draw[violet,decoration={markings, mark=at position 0.26 with {\arrow[>=stealth]{<}}},
        postaction={decorate},fill=white] (0,0) circle (20pt);
        \node[violet,above] at (0,20pt) {$\rho_2$};
        \draw[violet,decoration={markings, mark=at position 0.26 with {\arrow[>=stealth]{<}}},
        postaction={decorate},fill=white] (2.5,0) circle (20pt);
        \node[violet,above] at (2.5,20pt) {$\rho_3$};


        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}


\end{document}
```

But then it produces the following image 
[image]

As you can see, the positioning of the green lines is not correct anymore.
I didn't scale the picture, so I have no idea what went wrong.

Comment: Can make a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that reproduces the problem? If I just change the documentclass to `article` or similar the green lines are still at the correct position

Comment: Your code works well, i.e., it does not reproduce your problem, so it is difficult to help you. I think there must be some additional packages or commands which affect the picture -- and they should be shown here.

Comment: @mathstackuser May be use `resizebox` or `adjustbox`? I think `resizebox` comes with `graphicx` package and `adjustbox` is a package by itself.

Comment: @JouleV Actually the problem is when the OP compiles it by including in other documents (for example, a manuscript), the image compiles in its own size which is expected (because of how the OP drew) ;) So, if you compile it as standalone you wont see it (I think). May be put a grid line (`help lines`) on top it, you may be able to see the reason why :D.

Comment: @mathstackuser: Your main file uses the `12pt` option and the `standalone` file does not, and therefore as `10pt` active. That can affect the sizes if they are relative to the font size. Try the main document without `12pt` and see if the diagram is the same.

Comment: @MartinScharrer Thanks, that helps! Unfortunately, I need 12pt... Any idea how to solve that?

Comment: @mathstackuser: I posted an answer now.

Answer (score 8):

The problem are different font sizes (`12pt` in the main file and default 10pt font size in the diagram file as you use `\textwidth` to size your polygon and this length depends on the document default font size. You can either remove the font size dependency, e.g. by changing `\textwidth` with a explicit length (in the sub file it has a length of 345pt), or use the `standalone` *package* (!) in the main document with the `obeyclassoptions` option and then use `\includestandalone{filebasename}` to include the diagram file. The `standalone` package then will switch to the default font size automatically when including the code in the subfile.

```
\documentclass[oneside, a4paper, 12pt]{article}

\usepackage[obeyclassoptions]{standalone}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations, decorations.markings} 
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix, arrows, decorations.pathmorphing}


%==========================  Middle & pointing arrows ==========================%
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------%
% usage: \draw[->-] or \draw[->-=6pt red 1]
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------%
\tikzset{ ->-/.style args={#1 #2 #3}{
        decoration={markings,mark= at position 0.5 with {\arrow{stealth}}, }, 
        postaction={decorate}, }, 
    ->-/.default= {0.5 6pt black }}


%==========================  Middle & pointing arrows ==========================%
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------%
% usage: \draw[-<-] path; or \draw[-<-=6pt red 1] path;
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------%
\tikzset{ -<-/.style args={#1 #2 #3}{
        decoration={markings,mark= at position 0.5 with {\arrow[>=stealth]{<}}, }, 
        postaction={decorate}, }, 
    -<-/.default= {0.5 6pt black }}


\begin{document}


    \begin{center}
    \includestandalone{q470062_sub}% here q470062_sub.tex contains the TikZ picture, change to the used filename
    \end{center}


\end{document}
```

Further `standalone` package option can be helpful here, check the manual for the `subpreambles` option which collects the preambles of subfiles automatically.

If you load the `adjustbox` package with the `export` option before the `standalone` package, you can also use `\includestandalone[center]{q470062_sub}` to center the content as well as other `adjustbox` key to modify the diagram in size etc.

---

If this is all too complicate for you then just decrease the font size for the `tikzpicture` again. Within a 12pt document the `\footnotesize` macro gives you 10pt again. Place that directly before `\begin{tikzpicture}` and make sure that there is a group around it, like it is now due to the `center` environment.

Comment: Thanks! If I understand that right, I then have font size 10pt for my labels of the picture rigth? I would like to have the same everywhere. I removed the font size dependency in my code, which was not difficult here. I have similar problems with other pictures, where I calculated coordinates. How can I get rid of the font size dependency?

Comment: @mathstackuser: You are using `minimum size=0.9\textwidth` so the size of your polygon depends on the text width which depends on the default font size. For 10pt the `\textwidth` is 345pt and for 12pt it is 390pt. If you just that the size using an explicit value it works: `minimum size=310.5pt`.

Comment: @mathstackuser: You could also change the explicit starting point of the green lines `(0,-5.44)` with an anchor of the polygon node. Usually `(pol.south)` would work, but as you rotated the node I would use `(pol.75)` which means the outer side of node `pol` at 75 degrees. This way the lines always touch the outer side of the polygon. Its size however would still change if you not remove `\textwidth` in its size definition.

Comment: @mathstackuser: Ah, didn't see your answer. Sorry.

Answer (score 3):

The comments and answer by Martin Scharrer have already analysed that your problem is caused by the different font size. Here a minimal invasive attempt to workaround the problem:

```
    \documentclass[oneside, a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations, decorations.markings} 
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix, arrows, decorations.pathmorphing}


%==========================  Middle & pointing arrows ==========================%
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------%
% usage: \draw[->-] or \draw[->-=6pt red 1]
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------%
\tikzset{ ->-/.style args={#1 #2 #3}{
        decoration={markings,mark= at position 0.5 with {\arrow{stealth}}, }, 
        postaction={decorate}, }, 
    ->-/.default= {0.5 6pt black }}


%==========================  Middle & pointing arrows ==========================%
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------%
% usage: \draw[-<-] path; or \draw[-<-=6pt red 1] path;
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------%
\tikzset{ -<-/.style args={#1 #2 #3}{
        decoration={markings,mark= at position 0.5 with {\arrow[>=stealth]{<}}, }, 
        postaction={decorate}, }, 
    -<-/.default= {0.5 6pt black }}


    \begin{document}
    \begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    %Polygon 12 Seiten
    \node[fill=gray!10] (pol) [ 
    %draw, 
    minimum size=0.9\textwidth, regular polygon, regular polygon sides=12, rotate=195 ]{};
    \foreach \x/\y/\i in {1/2/1,5/6/2,9/10/3} %\alpha's
    \draw[black!10!red,auto=right,->-]
    (pol.corner \x)--(pol.corner \y)
    node[black!10!red,midway]{$\alpha_{\i}$};
    \foreach \x/\y/\i in {3/4/1,7/8/2,11/12/3} %inverse \alpha's
    \draw[black!10!red,auto=right,-<-]
    (pol.corner \x)--(pol.corner \y)
    node[black!10!red,midway]{$\alpha_{\i}$};
    \foreach \x/\y/\i in {2/3/1,6/7/2,10/11/3} %\beta's
    \draw[black!10!blue,auto=right,->-]
    (pol.corner \x)--(pol.corner \y)
    node[black!10!blue,midway]{$\beta_ {\i}$};
    \foreach \x/\y/\i in {4/5/1,8/9/2,12/1/3} %inverse \beta's
    \draw[black!10!blue,auto=right,-<-]
    (pol.corner \x)--(pol.corner \y)
    node[black!10!blue,midway]{$\beta_{\i}$};

        \coordinate(mycord) at (0,-6.15);

    %\xi's
    \draw[black!40!green,decoration={ markings, mark=at position 0.5 with {\arrow{stealth}}}, postaction={decorate}]  
    (mycord) --(-2.21,-0.63) node[midway, left] {$\xi_1$} ;
    \draw[black!40!green,decoration={ markings, mark=at position 0.5 with {\arrow{stealth}}}, postaction={decorate}]  
    (mycord) -- (0,-20pt) node[midway, left] {$\xi_2$};
    \draw[black!40!green,decoration={ markings, mark=at position 0.5 with {\arrow{stealth}}}, postaction={decorate}] 
    (mycord) -- (2.21,-0.63) node[midway, left] {$\xi_3$};

    % 3 Kreise mit Beschriftung
    \draw[violet,decoration={markings, mark=at position 0.26 with {\arrow[>=stealth]{<}}},
    postaction={decorate},fill=white] (-2.5,0) circle (20pt)  ;
    \node[violet,above] at (-2.5,20pt) {$\rho_1$};
    \draw[violet,decoration={markings, mark=at position 0.26 with {\arrow[>=stealth]{<}}},
    postaction={decorate},fill=white] (0,0) circle (20pt);
    \node[violet,above] at (0,20pt) {$\rho_2$};
    \draw[violet,decoration={markings, mark=at position 0.26 with {\arrow[>=stealth]{<}}},
    postaction={decorate},fill=white] (2.5,0) circle (20pt);
    \node[violet,above] at (2.5,20pt) {$\rho_3$};



    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to remove the font size dependency by using (pol.corner 1).

The following code produces the desired result.

```
\documentclass[oneside, a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations, decorations.markings} 
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix, arrows, decorations.pathmorphing}


%==========================  Middle & pointing arrows ==========================%
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------%
% usage: \draw[->-] or \draw[->-=6pt red 1]
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------%
\tikzset{ ->-/.style args={#1 #2 #3}{
        decoration={markings,mark= at position 0.5 with {\arrow{stealth}}, }, 
        postaction={decorate}, }, 
    ->-/.default= {0.5 6pt black }}


%==========================  Middle & pointing arrows ==========================%
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------%
% usage: \draw[-<-] path; or \draw[-<-=6pt red 1] path;
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------%
\tikzset{ -<-/.style args={#1 #2 #3}{
        decoration={markings,mark= at position 0.5 with {\arrow[>=stealth]{<}}, }, 
        postaction={decorate}, }, 
    -<-/.default= {0.5 6pt black }}


\begin{document}


    \begin{center}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        %Polygon 12 Seiten
        \node[fill=gray!10] (pol) [ 
        %draw, 
        minimum size=0.9\textwidth, regular polygon, regular polygon sides=12, rotate=195 ]{};
        \foreach \x/\y/\i in {1/2/1,5/6/2,9/10/3} %\alpha's
        \draw[black!10!red,auto=right,->-]
        (pol.corner \x)--(pol.corner \y)
        node[black!10!red,midway]{$\alpha_{\i}$};
        \foreach \x/\y/\i in {3/4/1,7/8/2,11/12/3} %inverse \alpha's
        \draw[black!10!red,auto=right,-<-]
        (pol.corner \x)--(pol.corner \y)
        node[black!10!red,midway]{$\alpha_{\i}$};
        \foreach \x/\y/\i in {2/3/1,6/7/2,10/11/3} %\beta's
        \draw[black!10!blue,auto=right,->-]
        (pol.corner \x)--(pol.corner \y)
        node[black!10!blue,midway]{$\beta_ {\i}$};
        \foreach \x/\y/\i in {4/5/1,8/9/2,12/1/3} %inverse \beta's
        \draw[black!10!blue,auto=right,-<-]
        (pol.corner \x)--(pol.corner \y)
        node[black!10!blue,midway]{$\beta_{\i}$};

        %\xi's
        \draw[black!40!green,decoration={ markings, mark=at position 0.5 with {\arrow{stealth}}}, postaction={decorate}]  
        (pol.corner 1) --(-2.21,-0.63) node[midway, left] {$\xi_1$} ;
        \draw[black!40!green,decoration={ markings, mark=at position 0.5 with {\arrow{stealth}}}, postaction={decorate}]  
        (pol.corner 1) -- (0,-20pt) node[midway, left] {$\xi_2$};
        \draw[black!40!green,decoration={ markings, mark=at position 0.5 with {\arrow{stealth}}}, postaction={decorate}] 
        (pol.corner 1) -- (2.21,-0.63) node[midway, left] {$\xi_3$};

        % 3 Kreise mit Beschriftung
        \draw[violet,decoration={markings, mark=at position 0.26 with {\arrow[>=stealth]{<}}},
        postaction={decorate},fill=white] (-2.5,0) circle (20pt)  ;
        \node[violet,above] at (-2.5,20pt) {$\rho_1$};
        \draw[violet,decoration={markings, mark=at position 0.26 with {\arrow[>=stealth]{<}}},
        postaction={decorate},fill=white] (0,0) circle (20pt);
        \node[violet,above] at (0,20pt) {$\rho_2$};
        \draw[violet,decoration={markings, mark=at position 0.26 with {\arrow[>=stealth]{<}}},
        postaction={decorate},fill=white] (2.5,0) circle (20pt);
        \node[violet,above] at (2.5,20pt) {$\rho_3$};


        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}


\end{document}
```